# EO.Web Pageview using dynamically add usercontrols

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the tabstrip and multipage controls from essential objects.
My goal is to dynamically build the tabstrip and pageviews based upon a dataset retrieved from a database.

So far the dynamic build is working, but I am having a issue with adding a usercontrol to each pageview.

This is my code so far...

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim ts As New EO.Web.TabStrip
    Dim mp As New EO.Web.MultiPage
    ts = tsProgramMenu
    mp = mpProgramMenu

    dt = bc.getGrantProgram(strConnection, strGrantProgramId, strActive)

    For Each dr In dt.Rows
        'MULTI PAGE PAGEVIEWS
        Dim p As New EO.Web.PageView
        p.ID = "pv" & dr.Item(1).ToString

        mp.PageViews.Add(p)
        'TOP ROW TAB ITEMS
        Dim x As New EO.Web.TabItem
        x.Text.Html = dr.Item(1).ToString
        x.ItemID = "ti" & dr.Item(1).ToString
        x.PageViewID = p.ID
        ts.TopGroup.Items.Add(x)

    Next
```

In the page source I can see the pageviews being created.

```
<table id="ctl00_MainContent_pvHMGP" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am just having trouble adding the usercontrol to the pageview.
Thanks for any and all assistance!!!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has an issue, this is what worked for me.

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim ts As New EO.Web.TabStrip
    Dim mp As New EO.Web.MultiPage
    ts = tsProgramMenu
    mp = mpProgramMenu

    dt = bc.getGrantProgram(strConnection, strGrantProgramId, strActive)

    For Each dr In dt.Rows
        'MULTI PAGE PAGEVIEWS
        Dim p As New EO.Web.PageView
        Dim uc As New UserControl
        Dim strUserControl As String

        strUserControl = dr.Item(1).ToString & ".ascx"
        uc.ID = "uc" & dr.Item(1).ToString
        p.ID = "pv" & dr.Item(1).ToString
        p.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl(strUserControl))

        mp.PageViews.Add(p)
        'TOP ROW TAB ITEMS
        Dim x As New EO.Web.TabItem
        x.Text.Html = dr.Item(1).ToString
        x.ItemID = "ti" & dr.Item(1).ToString
        x.PageViewID = p.ID
        ts.TopGroup.Items.Add(x)

    Next
```